# Rails cannot be started Load Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rbenv

I try to reinstall my rails and remove my .rbenv and install again. None of the methods work. I'm using rails 4.2.1.

Here's the error that I got when "rails server start":

```
/Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require': cannot load such file -- rack/handler/start (LoadError)
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:78:in `try_require'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/handler.rb:16:in `get'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/rack-1.6.4/lib/rack/server.rb:290:in `server'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:125:in `print_boot_information'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:75:in `start'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:80:in `block in server'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `tap'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:75:in `server'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/CQ/.rbenv/versions/2.2.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from bin/rails:8:in `require'
from bin/rails:8:in `<main>'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command is only `rails server` or `rails s`.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/command_line.html#rails-server